# Unable to instantiate activity inside another class

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to put the Activity class inside my custom view like this

```
public class AppLauncher extends LinearLayout
{
    // My custom view

    public class Settings extends Activity
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.app_launcher_settings);
        }
    }
}
```

and I started the activity with

```
Intent setting = new Intent(mContext, AppLauncher.Settings.class);
mContext.startActivity(setting);
```

but my app crash with error
`java.lang.Class<in.blackant.systemui.widget.AppLauncher$Settings> has no zero argument constructor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to put the Activity class inside my custom view like this

That is extremely strange.

> but my app crash with error `java.lang.Class<in.blackant.systemui.widget.AppLauncher$Settings>` has no zero argument constructor

That is because `Settings` is an inner class. Only `AppLauncher` can create an instance of it. As a result, the framework cannot create an instance of it.

If you really wish to keep this current structure, you would need to make `Settings` static:

```
public static class Settings extends Activity
```